# Why am I getting Failed to find documents in mongodb data api

Tags: javascript, mongodb, axios

I'm using mongodb Data api, here's my code:]

```js
items = await axios.post(`${process.env.DB_API_URL}/find`, {
                "collection":"",
                "database":"",
                "dataSource":"",
                "projection": {
                    '_id': {
                        $in : [
                            ...ids.map(id => ({$oid: id}))
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }, {
                headers: {
                    'api-key': process.env.DB_API_KEY,
                    'Content-Type': "application/json"
                }
            })
```

However, I'm getting this response:
 `data: 'Failed to find documents: FunctionError: projection is invalid'`
I suspect this error is occurring inside the value of property `$in`.

I also tried to use this:

```js
                "projection": {
                    '_id': {
                        $in : [
                            ...ids.map(id => id)
                        ]
                    }
                }
```

But this didn't work

Comment: isn't `projection` used to specify what fields to return? you seem to be using it as a `filter`

Comment: @GrafiCode It works, post is as an solution and I'll mark it